# Related to Computer UPS charging time

Tags: windows-7

I want to know about the charging time of a computer UPS.Normally I switch OFF the main power supply after my use, but is that correct?

My question is that as to how long should I charge my UPS after PC is shutdown? Is charging to be continued when  my computer is not in use?

Comment: Do you use a multiple socket outlet which you're switching off? And is the UPS connected to that multiple socket outlet?

Answer (score 0):

All modern computer equipment is designed to operate on 24/7 basis (always on). You should not be afraid to leave main switch ON (whatever switch you meant). UPS will not overcharge / explode / etc nor will it waste significant amount of electricity. UPS itself will take care for charging it's batteries. This process is fully transparent for end user.

Moreover, your computer has [Real Time Clock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_clock) which uses internal battery energy if computer is disconnected from external power source. So, I would recommend you leave your computer energized (it can be off, but power should be connected).

Comment: Satisfying explanation.Now I understood.